# 12V DC DMX LED Controller needs to be reduced to 5V

Tags: voltage, led, rgb, dmx

I need a bit of help for a lighting project I am undertaking.  I have a couple of 12 volt DMX LED controllers driving various zones in a bathroom with LED strip.

I want to replace the controlbox for the LEDs in the bath and drive it via my DMX system.  The output of the RGB bath controller is 5 volt per channel.

How can I reduce the output voltage from a 12 volt DMX RGB controller to be 5 volts?

Note the output voltage will need to vary based on the change of input voltage as the controller works through the various the various RGB colours.

Thanks for any input in advance,

Olly.

Comment: Can you have a separate 5 V supply? If yes, then all you need is three transistors and three resistors.

Comment: Hi Winny - I could easily add a 5V supply if needed.  What would your proposed idea look like?  Apologies, I never got to grips 100% with electronics at school and years later wish I had!!!

Comment: I’m mobile so no schematic editor but take a look at https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/124526/why-is-there-so-much-overshoot-in-my-led-circuit-and-how-do-i-prevent-it and replace your 12 V in the top right hand corner with 5 V and you are pretty much done.

Comment: thanks Winny.  So I take it, the PWM in would be my variable voltage (up to 12V) feed, and the 5v would just go to ground through the transistor.  Do I need R1? if so, how would I calculate what resistance it should be?  I know the 5V LEDs are rated at 0.6 amps based on the manufacturer details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can "inject" 5 V from a separate source, you can build your own low-side PWM like this:

EDIT: New schematic due to lowside PWM from your driver. This is kind of dirty. If you want to improve the efficiency and probably dimming at very low duty-cycles, you should consider an inverting gate driver instead of R1 and M1.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHbptc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Wow - thanks that's amazing!  I'll head out to Maplin tomorrow to buy my first ever transistors! and try to make this up :o)

Comment: @OllyThomas You're welcome but hold your horses. If your 12 V PWM output isn't a true 12 V driver but rather another low side PWM, you will need pull-up instead of pull-down. If you have a wireing diagram for it it would be easy to determine.

Comment: Hi Winny, Not been shopping yet!  This is the controller I am using: https://www.ultraleds.co.uk/px24500a-3-channel-x-6a-dmx-controller-constant-voltage.html
and this is the spec sheet for it: https://www.ultraleds.co.uk/fileuploader/download/download/?d=0&file=custom%2Fupload%2FFile-1387546228.pdf

Do appreciate you taking the time to look at this for me!  Olly.

Comment: Ah! As I expected! Not a true 12 V output but rather low side PWM. I'll update the schematic for you to reflect this.

Comment: Heck, it might even be simpler to just feed your 12 V device with 5 V directly and bypass any LDO inside it if it's 5 V MCU.

Comment: OR Or or, if the V+ is not connected internally, via diode or direct, just give 5 V to V+ and you are done!

Comment: ah -  like that!! Sometimes the simplest ideas are the best!  So  you're saying just drive the LEDs V+ with a separate 5V feed, and then the low side RGB can be left in place!  Genius!!

Comment: @OllyThomas Probably yes. I would stick a multimeter set to diode mode into V+ and the other probe at +12V and check first (both ways). No connection, then you are good to go.

Comment: Thanks Winny.  Interestingly I do get a connection between V+ out and +12V in.  What are your thoughts? Could there be the issue running the 5v?  I've ordered a 12v -> 5v converter that should be arriving tomorrow (https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B079NCT73M/ref=twister_B07B4YGWHL?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1)  Thanks again for your help so far.  Olly.

Comment: Connection as diode or connection as in continuity? Apply 12 V in and measure between ground and V+ with your multimeter set to volt.

Comment: I set my meter to --|>+  best I can do with ASCII and I get a beep from it in both directions (I normally use it for continuity testing in my car)  ground and V+ gives me 12V when I put 12V in.

Comment: Bummer! If you are willing to void the warranty, it can be modded internally. However, all is not lost. If the RGB outputs are open collector or open source, you might as well tie the + of your 5 V LED strip to +5 V from your external power supply without going to the DMX to RGB thingy at all and tie the ground of your 5 V supply to the ground of the 12 V supply.

Comment: haha!  Warranty is not a problem - I'm happy to learn from my mistakes :o)  Sounds like we've got a way forward.  I'll give it a try when the 5v transformer arrives and let you know how we get on!  Many Thanks again - Olly.

Comment: You’re quite welcome. If it was mine, I would crack it open, measure if the logic is 5V inside it and if so, bridge over the LDO and run the entire thing straight from the 5 V supply.

Comment: Hi Winny  just wanted to thank you again and to let you know that it's working fine with the +5V from the transformer using the low side switching on the 12V LED controller.  Thanks again for your help - I really do appreciate it.  What a great thing the internet is to put a question out on a forum like this and get it answered and resolved so quickly.  Plus - I've learned something new! 
 Great community.  Thanks again, Olly.